# Callback functions not executed correctly - Outlook add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm trying to create an Outlook add-in for testing purposes but I'm stuck with a weird behaviour. I declared, in my XML Manifest the following keys:

```
<FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <FunctionName>myEntryPoint</FunctionName>
</Action>
```

The 'functionFile' is my HTML file that contains the Javascript code.
In that HTML file, I've the following code:

```
(function () {
    Office.initialize = function (reason) { //Nothing here };
})();

function myEntryPoint(event) {

    Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageFormAsync({
         toRecipients: ["firstname.name@email.com"],
         subject: "Test Subject",
         htmlBody: "Internet headers: ",
    }, function (result) {
         console.log(result);
    });
    event.completed();
}
```

In fact, the method *displayNewMessageFormAsync* is executed but not the callback (**console.log(result)**).

If I put that code in the 'Office.initialize' function, the callback function is executed.

Any idea?

Comment: What platform are you on? (Outlook Desktop, OWA, Mac, etc.) Build numbers of those versions is also good to have. 

You may have a race condition in your code, (which may depend on platform). you are calling event.completed() after calling displayNewMessageFormAsync(). Which means the callback is not guaranteed to run. You can try setting a global variable to event, and calling event.completed() in the callback. or pass the event via the asyncContext.

Comment: I have to ask this or not - `{ //Nothing here }` or `{ /*Nothing here*/ }`

Comment: Could you please tell us the platform are you on along with the build no?

Comment: @StefanWang : You're right, I wrote the comment only here, I don't have it in my code.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT : I run the add-in on OutlookWebApp (20210103002.04). I'm on Windows 10 1809 (a shame I know) and I build the code with Visual Studio 2019 16.8.3.

Comment: @Pantharax, Please check which one is not working by console logging - `myEntryPoint` or `displayNewMessageFormAsync`

Comment: In fact, I just tried to pass the event in the asyncContext and it works as expected! The callback is executed. Problem solved, thank you very much to both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the comment of **Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT**:

> you are calling event.completed() after calling displayNewMessageFormAsync(). Which means the callback is not guaranteed to run. You can try setting a global variable to event, and calling event.completed() in the callback. or pass the event via the asyncContext.

I modified my code to pass the event in the asyncContext:

```
function myEntryPoint(event) {
    Office.context.mailbox.displayNewMessageFormAsync({
        toRecipients: ["firstname.name@email.com"],
        subject: "Test Subject",
        htmlBody: "Internet headers: ",
        }, 
        { asyncContext : event }, 
        function (result) {
             console.log(result);
             event.completed();
        }
    );
}
```

It works! Thank you.